# gunicorn: logfile directory owner being reset on reboot?

Tags: linux, logs

I have a droplet hosted in Digital Ocean runing Ubuntu 14.04.

I have a gunicorn log directory I made to store my logfiles and it only works if the owner is the user which is running the gunicorn process.

I do...

```
chown user gunicorn
```

but that only lasts until a reboot and then the ownership goes back to root and the group is adm. I am running a django process and I am not sure what to do. How can I make my change to a new owner permanent or would adding the user to the group adm work as well?

directory path is...

```
/var/log/gunicorn
```

ls -la the gunicorn directory...

```
drwxr-x---  2 root   adm        4096 Jan 30 20:08 .
drwxrwxr-x 12 root   syslog     4096 Jan 31 03:06 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 django django    73747 Jan 31 02:34 access.log
-rw-r--r--  1 django django 97698592 Jan 31 03:05 error.log
```

mount output..

```
/dev/vda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
```

ls -la /var/log | grep gunicorn...

```
drwxr-x---  2 root      adm           4096 Jan 30 20:08 gunicorn
```

/etc/init/gunicorn.conf...

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/django

exec venv/bin/gunicorn \
    --name=langalang \
    --pythonpath=langalang \
    --bind=0.0.0.0:9000 \
    --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
    langalang.wsgi:application
```

/etc/gunicorn.d/cunicorn.py...

```
"""gunicorn WSGI server configuration."""
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from os import environ


def max_workers():
    return cpu_count() * 2 + 1

max_requests = 1000
worker_class = 'gevent'
workers = max_workers()
errorlog = '/var/log/gunicorn/error.log'
accesslog = '/var/log/gunicorn/access.log'
```

Comment: What init system is your Linux using (`systemd`, `Upstart`, `sysvinit`)? You can also run the `chown` command from `/etc/rc.local`, that happens so late in the boot process, that the culprit probably already has broken things by chang ownership back to root.

Comment: it ususes upstart I believe, it is Ubuntu14.04

Comment: Please add the directory full path to the post.

Comment: added. @RuiFRibeiro

Comment: hmmm...I though you might be using /run...`ls -la /var/log/gunicorn` and the output of `mount`?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro . added. files in the directory do not change permissions, only the directory itself...

Comment: okay, so `ls -la /var/log | grep gunicorn` too please.

Comment: added, but if im not mistaken, that is the same output as '.' in the ls -la /var/log/gunicorn

Comment: hmmmm /dev/vda? is the server being provisioned again into each reboot by instance?

Comment: The ls | grep was to see if the directory was aliased to someplace else.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is about provisioning...It is a Digital Ocean droplet if that tells you anything...

Comment: yes, a VPS. know them only by name. let me check something.

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/init/gunicorn.conf`? if yes, please do show it here.

Comment: posted, also posted /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py where the logfiles are specified

Comment: ok some new information...I created a test directory chown'ed it and rebooted and nothing happened. I recreated the gunicorn directory and did the same and the owners went from django / adm to root / adm. Could it be something in the gunicorn logging configuration that is doing it?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out there was a script at /etc/init.d/gunicorn that was creating and giving the directory permissions everytime gunicorn started. I just changed the permissions in that file and everything works ok. That was really hard to find